# Request Reply and Scatter Gather Using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am attempting to construct a route which will do the following:

1. Consume a message from  `jms:sender-in`. I am using a `INOUT`request reply pattern. The `JMSReplyTo = sender-out`
2. The above message will be routed to multiple recipients like `jms:consumer1-in`, `jms:consumer2-in` and `jms:consumer3-in`. All are using a request reply pattern. The  `JMSReplyTo` is specified per consumer ( in this case, the `JMSReplyTo` are in this order `jms:consumer1-out, jms:consumer2-out, jms:consumer3-out`
3. I need to aggregate all the replies together and send the result back to `jms:sender-out`.

I constructed a route which will resemble this:

```
from("jms:sender-in")
    .to("jms:consumer1-in?exchangePattern=InOut&replyTo=queue:consumer1-out&preserveMessageQos=true")
    .to("jms:consumer2-in?exchangePattern=InOut&replyTo=queue:consumer2-out&preserveMessageQos=true")
    .to("jms:consumer3-in?exchangePattern=InOut&replyTo=queue:consumer3-out&preserveMessageQos=true");
```

I then send the replies back to some queue to gather and aggreagte:

```
from("jms:consumer1-out?preserveMessageQos=true").to("jms:gather");
from("jms:consumer1-out?preserveMessageQos=true").to("jms:gather");
from("jms:consumer1-out?preserveMessageQos=true").to("jms:gather");
from("jms:gather").aggregate(header("TransactionID"), new GatherResponses()).completionSize(3).to("jms:sender-out");
```

To emulate the behavior of my consumers, I added the following route:

```
from("jms:consumer1-in").setBody(body());
from("jms:consumer2-in").setBody(body());
from("jms:consumer3-in").setBody(body());
```

I am getting a couple off issues:

1. I am getting a timeout error on the replies. If I comment out the gather part, then no issues. Why is there a timeout even though the replies are coming back to the queue and then forwarded to another queue.
2. How can I store the original JMSReplyTo value so Camel is able to send the aggregated result back to the sender's reply queue.

I have a feeling that I am struggling with some basic concepts. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good question!

There are two things you need to consider

1. Don't mix the [exchange patterns](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html), Request Reply (InOut) vs Event
   message (InOnly). (Unless you have a good reason).
2. If you do a [scatter-gather](http://camel.apache.org/scatter-gather.html), you need to make the requests
   [multicast](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html), otherwise they will be [pipelined](http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html) which is not
   really [scatter-gather](http://camel.apache.org/scatter-gather.html).

I've made two examples which are similar to your case - one with Request Reply and one with (one way) Event messages.

*Feel free to replace the activemq component with jms - it's the same thing in these examples.*

Example one, using event messages - InOnly:

```
from("activemq:amq.in")
    .multicast()
        .to("activemq:amq.q1")
        .to("activemq:amq.q2")
        .to("activemq:amq.q3");

from("activemq:amq.q1").setBody(constant("q1")).to("activemq:amq.gather");
from("activemq:amq.q2").setBody(constant("q2")).to("activemq:amq.gather");
from("activemq:amq.q3").setBody(constant("q3")).to("activemq:amq.gather");

from("activemq:amq.gather")
    .aggregate(new ConcatAggregationStrategy())
        .header("breadcrumbId")
        .completionSize(3)
        .to("activemq:amq.out");

from("activemq:amq.out")
    .log("${body}"); // logs "q1q2q3"
```

Example two, using Request reply - note that the scattering route has to gather the responses as they come in. The result is the same as the first example, but with less routes and less configuration.

```
from("activemq:amq.in2")
    .multicast(new ConcatAggregationStrategy())
        .inOut("activemq:amq.q4")
        .inOut("activemq:amq.q5")
        .inOut("activemq:amq.q6")
    .end()
    .log("Received replies: ${body}"); // logs "q4q5q6"

from("activemq:amq.q4").setBody(constant("q4"));
from("activemq:amq.q5").setBody(constant("q5"));
from("activemq:amq.q6").setBody(constant("q6"));
```

As for your question two - of course, it's possible to pass around JMSReplyTo headers and force exchange patterns along the road - but you will create hard to debug code. Keep your exchange patterns simple and clean - it keep bugs away.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Petter. I was not aware that I can do this:  `.multicast(new ConcatAggregationStrategy())`. This solves the problem at hand.

Comment: Nearly 5 years later and still the best answer!